# How to bind list items to wrap panel in windows phone

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

How to bind list items to Wrap Panel,
I got result like below:

1
2
3
4

but I want like this:

1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8

Comment: post what you have tried

Comment: share your ListBox itemtemplate and datatemplate

Comment: ohh..I got the solution. see answer,
it was XAML issue.
I just add ItemsPanel tag and ItemsPanel Template.

Answer (score 0):

```
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

                            <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="50" Width="100"/>

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" FontSize="22" Height="30" Margin="10" Width="110" TextAlignment="Center"/>

                        </StackPanel>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Controls:WrapPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ListBox>
```